# Why do those divs overlap?

Tags: css

What I want is simple:

[copyright                     vimeo | facebook | twitter    share]

But my divs overlap. Or they go outside the footer. Or they hurt my brain in another way. Also I feel like I have way to much css for the simple things I want. How can this be done in a clean matter?

```
<div class="footer">

    <div class="copyright">
        <p>© 2016 css hurts my brain</p>
    </div>

    <div class="social-media">
        <div>Vimeo</div>
        <div>Facebook</div>
        <div>Twitter</div>
    </div>

    <div class="share-menu-button">
        SHARE
    </div>

</div>


.footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 20;
}

.footer .copyright {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    float: left;
}

.footer .social-media {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    float: left;
}

.footer .share-menu-button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    float: left;
}

.social-media div {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css has several problems:

1. when using `position:absolute`, float has no effect.
2. when using `position:absolute`, all absolute positioned elements are stacked (unless you give them different positions)

Just use floats with no positions:

```
 .footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    background: #000;
    color: white;
}

.footer >div , .social-media > div{
  padding: 16px 20px;
}

.footer .copyright {
    float: left;
}

.footer .social-media {
    float: left;
}

.footer .share-menu-button {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.social-media div {
    float:left;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kg6v5vjk/1/

Comment: Thanks, you just pulled me out of a really angry mode :)

Comment: Why does the order of elements change when I use this?: `.footer .social-media {
    float: right;
}

.footer .share-menu-button {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 16px;
}`

Comment: Also this is css for me:
Q: How can I get a div to the bottom A: Use position absolute and...
Q: How can I do... A: don't use position absolute...

Comment: That's the way floats work, the first element always remain first, so if you float right, the first element would be the first on the right and so on. It seems like you need to learn CSS a bit deeper, there are a lot of written/video materials on the web.

Comment: Nah i'm gonna quit webdesign :)

Answer (score 0):

why not just use  , theres no need to create a div for a standard formatting procedure given in html. That may solve a problem.

Also no need to use div around each VIMEO, FACEBOOK, TWITTER, instead just use

```
<p> Vimeo, Facebook, Twitter </p>
```

if you want to make them links then its similar

```
<p>
<a href="vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>
<a href="facebook.com">Facebook</a>`enter code here`
<a href="twitter.com">Vimeo</a>
</p>
```

Theres no need to use so many Divs